# Why do iOS and Android force you to write the UI in the native App Programming language?

Tags: android, ios

:) When you write a iOS App, in order to use the UI like buttons. you have to write it in Objective-C. (Java on Android). I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts on the technical reasoning behind this. Why they might of done this. As you can write apps in C++ on iOS so I've never fully worked out why they didn't expose a way of making the UI in that. (Ignoring the fact that this is how they did it on the Mac).

Note: I know you can write apps in c++ for Android but the question is more why is the main UI i.e buttons etc forced to be written in a dynamic language for these platforms, why not expose access to it thorough C++ without having to write a crude wrapper or binding layer yourself.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean? What I understand is like "Do I have to write in C++ to make a C++ program or can I write HTML"

Comment: :) When you write a iOS App, in order to use the UI like buttons. you have to write it in Objective-C. (Java on Android). I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts on the technical reasoning behind this. Why they might of done this. As you can write apps in C++ on iOS so I've never fully worked out why they didn't expose a way of making the UI in that.

Comment: You can use the NDK(native development kit) on Android to write your app in C++.

Comment: I don't think C++ was around when Objective-C was created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that when the original framework engineers were working on their respective operating systems, cross-platform desires like UI support in a different language like C++ was at the bottom of their concerns. You'll have to realize that when deadlines loom, all of the features are prioritized only what is considered most important is made to work. Everything else is a consequence of that.

In the case of iOS, Objective-C is the language of choice for the OS that Apple uses. All of the MacOS app developers were writing in Objective-C so their developer based was in familiar territory.

In the case of Android, Java was already a popular language, with existing open source tooling and libraries (Eclipse IDE, Apache Harmony), so presumably they decided to use Java as the first class language for app development with apps running in a VM as a consequence. Alternatively the decision may have been VM first for the sandboxing of apps and Java was picked as the language for app developers. Or some other reason.

In either case any attempt to add in additional languages now that both are in the hands of customers means design decisions and trade offs along with a host of other questions like: how to add it in without breaking existing APIs, how to support it along with new features, how to test, etc. etc.

As you see more and more software, you'll realize that lots of stuff is just arbitrary or made sense at the moment of when it was designed.

Answer (score 2):

iOS does expose a C API for drawing UI components; it's called Core Graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Because the view itself is written in Objective-C, or Java, respectively. When in Rome, do as the Romans do.